# Table Border is Not working : Table Row (tr) Border does not appear using CSS

Tags: html, css

Here is my Stylesheet

```
<style>
table tr{ border:1px solid #F00 ;  }
table td{ padding:20px; }
</style>
```

Here is a HTML CODE :

```
<table class="" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>testing</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is a Fiddle link for live preview.
http://jsfiddle.net/Husen/tL7wK/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add border to td for example:

```
<style>
table td{ padding:20px; border:1px solid #F00 ; }
</style>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tL7wK/1/)

Or you can add border to the table:
like this:

```
table{ border:1px solid #F00 ;  }
table td{ padding:20px; }
```

[**DEMO2**](http://jsfiddle.net/tL7wK/2/)

If you want only row border effect you can try this:

```
table td{
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    padding:20px; 
 }

 table{ border:1px solid #F00 ;  }
```

[**DEMO3**](http://jsfiddle.net/tL7wK/4/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but, i need rowwise border only, not cellwise

Comment: see my update please demo3 @Husen

Comment: my demo3 works on all version of IE @Husen

Comment: Hey, this is a pretty cool solution, even works fine with IE7. But we can not give table{ border:1px solid #F00 ;  } otherwise there will be double border come at top and bottom row. I am posting the final solution here.

Comment: Here is the fiddle link for final solution brother http://jsfiddle.net/Husen/tL7wK/12/

Answer (score 10):

Remove the `table`s `border`  attribute.

Add `border-collapse: collapse;` to your CSS. This will allow a border for the `tr` :)

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr {
  border: 1px solid #F00;
  border-top: 1px solid #0F0;
}

table td {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>testing</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Amazing!!! this works fine, but not compatible with IE7 :(, but, works well with rest browsers. Do you have hack or code for IE7?

Comment: Not working , but, i've find a solution like this : 
http://jsfiddle.net/Husen/tL7wK/11/

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
table td{ border:1px solid #F00 ;padding:20px;  }
```